# Django ignore extra arguments on constructing model

Tags: python, django, django-models, constructor

I have a small Django project where I get some information from an external source and use it to construct a model instance.  The problem is that the source returns a lot (and I mean a lot!) of extra information which I don't need.

At the moment I am having to work out which extra records are in there and manually go through and delete each one.  But this isn't very good because

1. It makes for very ugly code and
2. If the external source changes, e.g. it adds a new field, my code will throw an error when I construct a model

   ```
   myModel = MyModel(**argDict)
   ```

Is there a way I can pass an over-complete `argDict` to my model and have it suppress any errors about extra information and just discard it?  I was thinking that I could use a `pre_init` signal but then I still didn't know how stop that error being given back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [meta API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/) provides a list of all available field instances via `get_fields()`. You could write a utility function to filter kwargs for the `init`:

```
def init_kwargs(model, arg_dict):
    model_fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()]
    return {k: v for k, v in arg_dict.items() if k in model_fields}
```

then,

```
kwars = init_kwargs(myModel, arg_dict)
myModel = MyModel(**kwargs)
```

will work for all models.

Comment: Using the meta api is a good idea, but I would avoid overriding the model's `__init__` method. A couple of alternatives are to define a function e.g. `create_model_from_external_data(**argDict)` or a manager method e.g. `MyModel.objects.create_from_external_data(**argDict)`.

Comment: Agreed, there are various ways to achieve it. But why avoid overriding `__init__` in general as long as you call the original `__init__`?

Comment: The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) encourage alternatives to overriding `__init__`. In this case, I think it's better to call a method that makes it explicit that you are discarding data, rather than changing the behaviour everywhere in your application, which might hide subtle bugs.

Comment: I assume init_kwargs here be a class method?  Or does it need to be passed an instance?

Comment: @Alasdair I have to agree. Clients might rely on Errors to be raised for superfluous kwargs and overriding `__init__` would change that behaviour. Edited my answer, thx for clarifying!

Comment: @JMzance No, a common function somewhere in your project will do. Making it a class method of your `myModel` would reduce its reusability (given that you replace the `model` arg by `cls`).

Comment: I understand.  In this instance I only need it for a one off but I see your point.  Cheers!

Comment: For Python3: replace arg_dict.iteritems() with arg_dict.items()

Answer (score 2):

Create a blank instance without any arguments. Then use `setattr` to set the values. You should not get any errors for fields that do not exist on the model.

```
my_model = MyModel()
for key, value in argDict.items():
    setattr(my_model, key, value)
my_model.save()
```

You could wrap the above code in a function for reusability, perhaps a method on a custom manager.

Answer (score 1):

I need to alter the accepted answer to get this to work (Python 3.6.3):

```
def init_kwargs(model, arg_dict):
return {
    k: v for k, v in arg_dict.items() if k in [
       f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()
    ]
}
```